# The convergence of a semi-recursive series

Tags: real-analysis

The series $a_n$ is such that $0\le a_{n+m}\le a_n+a_m$ (for all $m,n$). Prove that $\frac{a_n}{n}$ is convergent.

Comment: Is there anything you tried solving this problem? How did you encounter this problem (why is it interesting)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a result well known as [Fekete's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subadditivity#Properties).